# Custodian badge- how to complete the review task?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

While trying to review a task, it says:

> You need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits

That means I can get the **Custodian** only after 2000 rep for the suggested edits(if i've got everything right :P)

BUT, I can see that this badge was recently rewarded to the users with less than 10 rep. How come?

I may be wrong at some point, but please help me clearing out this doubt.

Comment: If there's one thing I ask, it's that you don't just review posts to earn badges. Do so because you honestly care to check on the quality of incoming content.

Comment: @BradLarson, that's not the way incentives work.  We incentivize people so that they will be more motivated to do the action we desire.  It's not wrong to get rep or badges, it's just wrong to do sloppy work to get it.

Comment: Hi Brad, trust me I do that with full honesty. I am a learner and to help the people. I am participating actively in facebook api forum. Not just about the badge, was just curious :)

Comment: @Sahil - Great to hear. We appreciate the help, particularly when it comes to keeping the Facebook tags clean. Man, are they a mess.

Comment: Yes, messy and moderators are less there (but they are doing great)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can approve a suggested edit on your own post regardless of your reputation level.  This is how [user1946481](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1946481/user1946481) (for one example) got the Custodian badge for approving an edit to [Creating a hierarchy based on a self referencing table in MS Access '10 using treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14161332/1288).